# What does 0[str] means in C where str is a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

While I was learning Strings in C I came across the following piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[15] = "Hello, World";

    printf("str[0] = %c\n", str[0]);
    printf("*(str + 0) = %c\n", *(str + 0));
    printf("*(0 + str) = %c\n", *(0 + str));
    printf("0[str] = %c\n", 0[str]); /* This line 0[str] */

    return 0;
}
```

Simple things what I can figured out from the program are

`str[0]` will produce **H**
`*(str + 0)` will also produce **H** as it uses pointer arithmetic
`*(0 + str)` is similar to `*(str + 0)` and will also produce **H**

What I can't figure out is what does `0[str]` means and how does it evaluates to **H**. As what I have learnt is `[ ]` symbol represents an array and `0` is not an array.

Comment: Although this is a duplicate - when viewed from that angle - what is the purpose of a `+0`? Or is that jut an unfortunate value?

Answer (score 2):

consder the code below,

```
char str[10];
```

`str` will return the starting address address of the array `str[10]`.

So in your example `*(str + i)` will return the element `str[i]`.

`str[i] = i[str]` because addition is commutative.
Since `*(str + i)` and `*(i + str)` are equal because `i + str = str + i`.

Specifically `0[str] = str[0]` because `*(str+0) = *(0+str)`.
Because `str+0 = 0+str =str`.